# Update 7000+ attribute column at once?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, error-999999

ArcMap. I have a string field "Zonenumber" that contains 7000+ lines. This field contains various zoning designations. I need to update every single one of these selected properties to a single zone.

How do I do this? Going to field calculator and typing in the new zone does not work, see error below.

[image]

**EDIT**

Field calculator and putting in the new zone, 'R6', gives an error. Here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  A good question should include information about what you have tried, and where you are stuck.  What errors are you encountering?

Comment: It says "Syntax error". Can you post a screenshot of the field calculator with the value that you entered?

Comment: looks like your not editing the attribute table. please provide more information version and type of data (geodatabase)

Comment: Use double quote, type of data doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Just type the desired zone in single quotes into the field calculator, i.e.: `'zone'`.

Comment: I tried that and it throws an error.

Comment: @jdks18 What is the error?

Comment: Is there a domain in use on this field, and is the new zone code part of that domain?

Comment: Use double quote.

Answer (score -1):

Find and Replace worked best.

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012044